# Mix-blend-mode: Multiply Bug in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm attempting to implement mix-blend-mode in Firefox, which appears to be supported, but I only get black elements when using 'multiply'. Does anyone know why this happens? How to fix it?

Here's a link to the issue recreated in Codepen: http://codepen.io/anater/pen/xGWddq

```
.circle-red,
.circle-blue{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.circle-red{
  background: red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-75%, -50%);
}

.circle-blue{
  background: blue;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-25%, -50%);
}
```

This does not occur in Chrome or Safari, it is isolated to Firefox.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work for me either, but strangely, when I generate a screenshot using BrowserShots, it displays correctly in FF 37 on Mac or PC: https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/f37e07399b18388508c1223e6d402fa65990f878

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But the correct result when multiplying red and blue **is** black

To test it, better set different colors, cyan and yellow for instance

```css
.circle-red,
.circle-blue{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.circle-red{
  background: rgb(255, 255, 0);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-75%, -50%);
}

.circle-blue{
  background: rgb(0, 255, 255);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-25%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-red"></div>
<div class="circle-blue"></div>
```

I can no longer test it, but in the previous version of Firefox, there was a problem involving the mix-blend-mode and the base element (in this case, body) missing a background-color.

Can you try to set

```
body {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that it's displaying both circles entirely black, not just where they overlap...

Comment: @ChrisFletcher I am using FF 37.0.2 and I see it ok (intersection black, remaining sectors red & blue)

Comment: @ChrisFletcher Added note about posible source of problem (untested)

Comment: I see it black in firefox, both elements

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and this solved it for me: 
Set your color (being multiplied) using rgba with an "a" value of 0.99 instead of plain rgb.

Comment: Really didn't expect this to work, but it does just as you'd expect multiply to. Accepted answer above ends up with both circles black in Firefox 41.0.1.

Comment: Strangely this bug has reappeared for me on Firefox v106.0.1 (Win7) and this solution fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be due to a bug in FF for Mac:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1135271

A solution that worked for me (with rectangular DIVs) was applying a transparent outline to the div!

See:

https://medium.com/@maykelesser/how-to-fix-osx-firefox-mix-blend-mode-bug-6b3548e9e546

And the answer from Paule_D on

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable hardware acceleration in Firefox (Option>Advanced>Use hardware acceleration when available OFF)

Comment: This is not in any way related to the bug.